# Unable to read nodes for XML - Tridion Web 8.5

Tags: 2011, web8.5

While upgrading from Tridion 2011 to Web 8.5, unable to read nodes from XML. There are no values going in foreach.

```
XmlDocument config = new XmlDocument();                
config.LoadXml(xml);          
XmlNodeList doc = config.SelectNodes(Xpath);
foreach (XmlNode x in doc)
{
    HTValue.Add(x.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString(), x.Attributes["value"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Hash Name :" + x.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString() + " Hash Value : " + x.Attributes["value"].Value);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Trdionstackexchange swapnil!, Please explain a bit more detail about what you are trying to do? what you are trying access? using core service or TOM.NET API?

Comment: And how does the variable get filled? With what XML?

Comment: It clearly looks like the issue is with how the value of xml and xpath are being populated, whether the right namespaces are being used, etc.

Comment: @Velmurugan I am using core services. I checked the count of nodes is coming but when trying to retrieve value it is null.

Comment: @Quirijn yes the variable is filled with XML.

Comment: @NunoLinhares the value of XPath is being passed to the method to the method and XML is being read from web Dav URL

Comment: OK - can you check what is in the XML, can you check what is in the XPATH, and try to understand why SelectNodes is not returning anything? If the XML is valid and the XPATH is valid, then this would point at a problem with Microsoft's System.Xml, which is very unlikely.

Comment: Reasoning without any insight into XPath or Xml used. 
#1: XPath & XML must be "loadable" otherwise an exception would occur on load or .SelectNodes.
#2: Assuming namespace usage in XML, the XPath must be 100% "vebose" or it will fail.

Doesn't "SelectNodes" with "prefixed" XPath query require a "NamespaceManager" as 2nd parameter?

Comment: @MarvinSmit I have used the namespace option as well. I am not sure if the tridion web 8.5 is supporting that. I used the below namespace

 xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")

Comment: Have a look at the top of your XML document. The xmlns="..." xmlns:xlink=".." stuff. To have selectNodes pick up the elements you expect, make sure to: #add the same namespaces (same prefix's is common use, but not mandatory) to the namespace mananger.#supply that namespacemanager as second parameter to the selectnodes call. #make sure your XPath statement uses those prefixes.

Comment: We are trying to read values from XML in a component using Web Dav URL . The XML is read correctly. 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- keys specific to auto-publish -->
    <add key="abc" value="xyz" />
    <add key="abcd" value="pqr"/>
    <add key= "abce" value="/Building%20Blocks/Content/def.xml"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

Comment: xpath being sent to method is "configuration/appSettings/add"

not sure why the doc is empty and not being populated

XmlNodeList doc = config.SelectNodes(Xpath);


                foreach (XmlNode x in doc)
                {
                    HTValue.Add(x.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString(), x.Attributes["value"].Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("Hash Name :" + x.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString() + " Hash Value : " + x.Attributes["value"].Value);
                   
     }

Comment: No namespaces at all, so no namespace manager needed. Can you try adding a / as first character in your XPath query (e.g. root element) otherwise try doing a XmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes().

Comment: @MarvinSmit if using documentElement it is throwing an error 
"Root element is missing.. Stack Trace :    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)"

Comment: XPath value you have to use "//add" or "/configuration/appSettings/add" then it should work

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code and comments about what you are trying to do.

Indeed your code seems to be okay, your XPath value is the one problem based on your input XML and XPath value.

You could try this sample code it works.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string XML = $"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><configuration><appSettings><!--keys specific to auto-publish--><add key=\"abc\" value=\"xyz\" /><add key=\"abcd\" value=\"pqr\" /><add key=\"abce\" value=\"/Building%20Blocks/Content/def.xml\" /></appSettings></configuration>";
            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(XML);
            foreach (XElement element in document.Root.XPathSelectElements("/configuration/appSettings/add"))
            {
                string key = element.Attribute("key") != null ? element.Attribute("key").Value : string.Empty;
                string value = element.Attribute("value") != null ? element.Attribute("value").Value : string.Empty;
                Console.WriteLine($"Key: {key}, Value: {value}");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.